# How to use do while

Tags: c#

```cs
double x;

do
{
    Console.Write("Please enter a x value:");
    if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out x))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have entered wrong value. Please try again.");
    }
} while (true);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is my code. And I want the `do while` loop to work when the user entered no double value. What do I need to write in `while()`?

Comment: Instead `while (true)` use `while (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out x))` and in your `if` add the logic you need, like `Console.WriteLine("Value is: " + x.ToString());`

Comment: Try putting break; in if part. That is one way to do that (and ReadLine() is a useless addition).

Comment: Provided that you want to ask for the input until the user inputs a valid value *once*, and after that exit the loop, your `while(true)` is fine. Just put `break;` inside the `if`.

Comment: Difference in while loop and do/while loop is that in do/while, your code block is always executed before the condition in while is checked. in while, your code will Only execute, if condition passes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use result of TryParse

```
bool ok;
do
{
    Console.Write("Please enter a x value:");
    if (ok = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out x))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have entered wrong value. Please try again.");
    }
} while (!ok);
```

Comment: not if you define ok variable .... (corrected in answer)

Comment: I didn't know you can use `if (ok = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out x))` - but, it is needed declare and initialize `x` variable as double. I check it here [https://dotnetfiddle.net/](https://dotnetfiddle.net/).

Comment: I know... this answer isn't complete code, it only shows how to resolve problem...

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes you don't event need the `x` var or the `ok` var... it can be done without them, but it's not of importance here.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ hence the +1 for `if (ok = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out x))`.